# FOR works at prompt, but not in script file?

Tags: windows, scripting, command-line-interface

As part of a task that I am working on for a customer, I need to make some modifications to the enterprise logon script. Windows command-line is definitely not my area of expertise, but I am doing OK with most of it. However, I am running into the following inconsistent behavior, that I cannot figure out.

The following commands:

```
Set TMP=
For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %A in ('ipconfig ^| Find "Default Gateway" ^| Findstr/N "."') do (If not defined TMP  Set TMP=%~C)
```

When executed at the command prompt (a windows 7 CMD.EXE window), work as expected and TMP gets set with the IP address of my default gateway.  However, if I execute the exact same commands from a CMD file, *in the same window*, it fails with the following output (Echo On):

```
>Set TMP=
~C) was unexpected at this time.

>For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" ~C)
```

I have tried both CALL and running the script directly.  I have tried it both with and without `usebackq`, and with and without the parenthesis after the `DO`, with the same results every time: it works interactively, but not from a script in the same session.

What the heck is going on here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a part of `help for` cmd output:

```
To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.
```

Comment: Yep that was it!  Any idea why the extra "%" is necessary in command files?

Comment: It's comes from Windows Command interpreter origins (MS DOS). Seems http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634/en-us reveals it.